# Connection leakage with multiple threads -jboss+spring+hibernate

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, jboss

I am new to connection management in **jboss and hibernate**.I have an application using **spring + hibernate** running on **jboss 7.I** did some reading but have few doubts now:

1. How are connections and threads related to access a application.
2. Suppose i have maximum pool size of 10.Does it mean only 10 threads
   can access my application to perform database operations at a time?

If no, what happens when there are more than 10 threads say 15 or 20 accessing it?

**Does other threads wait for running threads to complete and they run next?**

(or)

**This results in a connection error like no managed connections available?**